# How to get the resource link for a glue job in the StepFunction state machine execution event history?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I'm using StepFunction to start a glue job, oddly I found in the `Execution event history` I couldn't get a resource link to this glue job, whereas it can give me the correspoding Lambda & logs link, am I missing permissions in the step function execution role?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience I've seen a few issues regarding showing the resource here. To be honest, it's probably a bug on the console that's not showing it.

My only other idea is based on how you invoke the Lambda task, are you using resource to start this? Are you something like using?

..

"Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:HelloFunction",

..

It could be that you need to specify the arn as the resource, which I'm not sure Glue even allows.

Comment: Hi I'm using `"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:getJobRun.sync"` for glue job, similarly I have a SageMaker batch job using the similar resource type in stepfunction and it gives me the resource link, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I would think it's just a console bug then to be honest, I've seen the same issue with invoking another Step Function as an integration.